# Getting all acceptable string arguments to DataFrameGroupby.aggregate

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

So, I have a piece of code that takes a groupby object and a dictionary mapping columns in the groupby to strings, indicating aggregation types. I want to validate that all the values in the dictionary are strings that pandas accepts in its aggregation. However, I don't want to use a try/except (which, without a loop, will only catch a single problem value). How do I do this?

I've already tried importing the SelectionMixin from pandas.core.generic and checking against the values in SelectionMixin._cython_table, but this clearly isn't an exhaustive list. My version of pandas is 0.20.3.

Here's an example of how I want to use this

```py
class SomeModule:

    ALLOWED_AGGREGATIONS = # this is where I would save the collection of allowed values

    @classmethod
    def aggregate(cls, df, groupby_cols, aggregation_dict):
        disallowed_aggregations = list(
            set(aggregation_dict.values) - set(cls.ALLOWED_AGGREGATIONS)
        )
        if len(disallowed_aggregations):
            val_str = ', '.join(disallowed_aggregations)
            raise ValueError(
                f'Unallowed aggregations found: {val_str}'
            )
        return df.groupby(groupby_cols).agg(aggregation_dict)
```